# Struts2 jQuery struts-plugin.xml invalid

Tags: java, struts2, apache-commons, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have setup a project which is a combo of Struts2 + Springs + JPA.

I recently came across the [Struts2-Jquery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)

Using this plugin (struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar) in my project I got an error

```
Unable to load jar:file:/H:/My%20Project/phase1/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.5.1.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 195 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:195:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:909)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 48 more


 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
        ... 53 more
```

The solution to this particular error was given [here](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=800) as Struts2 DTD problem.

Acting in the solution given in the above link..  updated three libraries in my webapp lib folder:

- Struts2-core-2.3.4.1
- struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.4.1
- xwork-core-2.3.4.1

When trying to deploy after this update I got this stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:209)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:210)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:437)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:856)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:353)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 52 more
```

Can anyone give me a pointer where I am going wrong ?

Comment: You may have multiple versions of `commons-lang3-xxxx.jar`. Pay attention to the `3`.

Comment: @AndreaLigios :) i dont have any commons-lang3-xxx.jar in my app 

The commons i included are just 
           commons-collections-3.1.jar,
           commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar,
           commons-io-1.3.2.jar,
           commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Then add it :) 
`org/apache/commons/**lang3**/StringUtils`

Comment: @AndreaLigios Looks like that solves the problem for application to run :)... But jquery Plugin not working....

Used a simple anchor tag targeting a div to change the content inside the div, but no success!

Comment: Then this is another question :) Be sure to take a look at the http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action. I'll Add the comment as answer to help future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: @AndreaLigios My bad ... hehe :) had forgotten to include <sj:head/> :P.... Works awesome now!

Comment: Great! This (sj:head) happened to my coworker too some time ago, I guess it's pretty common :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504174/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-lang3-stringutils)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `commons-lang3-3.x.jar` to your classpath for the filter to run.

You must ensure you don't have multiple versions of `commons-lang3-x.x.jar` too.

`commons-lang3-x.x.jar` and `commons-lang-x.x.jar` instead can coexist in the same classpath, because the `package` is different (they did it on purpose ;)

---

This can be known, because of *NoClassDefFoundError*:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.

which occurs mostly in two cases:

- at runtime, you doesn't have the library,
- or you have two versions of the library, hence the classloader doesn't know which to pick, and raises the exception.

The lang3 in the package means that the StringUtils class missing is from `common-lang3-*.jar`, not from `common-lang-*.jar`.

Comment: How did u spotted he is missing commons-lang3-x.x.jar

Comment: Because of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`. NoClassDefFoundError occurs mostly in two cases: at runtime, you doesn't have the library, or you have two versions of the library, hence the classloader doesn't know which to pick, and raises the exception. The `lang3` in the package means that the StringUtils class missing is from `common-lang3-*.jar`, not from `common-lang-*.jar` ;)