# HTTP STATUS 404: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, sql, string, jsp, struts2

I have this error when i started login.jsp form and type a username and password
The error was
HTTP STATUS 404: The requested resource is not available.

What am i missing? any help?

LoginAction.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

 private String user;
 private String password;
 private String name;

public String execute() {
  String ret = ERROR;
  Connection conn = null;

  try {
     String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/struts_tutorial";
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "");
     String sql = "SELECT name FROM login WHERE";
     sql+=" user = ? AND password = ?";
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setString(1, user);
     ps.setString(2, password);
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

     while (rs.next()) {
        name = rs.getString(1);
        ret = SUCCESS;
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     ret = ERROR;
  } finally {
     if (conn != null) {
        try {
           conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
     }
  }
  return ret;
 }

public String getUser() {
  return user;
 }

public void setUser(String user) {
  this.user = user;
 }

public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

Login.jsp

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Login Example</title>
 </head>
    <body>
    <html:form action="/login" focus="userName">
      Username : <html:text property="userName" />
    <br>
      Password : <html:password property="password" />
    <br>
     <html:submit value="login" />
    </html:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Struts Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
  <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="loginaction" 
      class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.LoginAction"
      method="execute">
     <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
     <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>

  </package>

 </struts>
```

This is what i tried
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_database_access.htm

Comment: Where is the mapping between /login and LoginAction?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18419661/573032

Comment: please show struts configuration file

Comment: Added Struts Configuration file

Answer (score 1):

[So many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124796/1654265) these days abount not working examples from tutorialspoint :(

Those tutorials are **old**, many things have changed.

1. Change the old FilterDispatcher [to the new StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103563/1654265);
2. Include [commons-lang3-3.x.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567240/1654265) in your project;
3. Change the version of your Servlet API according to a) your `servlet-api-x.x.jar` and b) your Servlet Container capabilities (eg. you need to ensure your Application Server is suporting Servlet API 3.0 if you want to use them... remember to not include the servelt-api jar in your WAR / EAR): you have a mixed config, specifying both 2.5 and 3.0

   ```xml
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   ```

   , [fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146372/1654265);
4. Ensure you have [all the required Struts2 libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22931920/1654265), all aligned to the latest version (2.3.16.3 currently), with all their dependences.

Then it should work.

After that, you can start looking for best practices, like using `<s:` (default prefix for Struts2) instead of `<html:` (default prefix for Struts1), and [connecting to a database from a business/DAO layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837913/1654265) instead that from the controller (Action).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But problem is same.  i think there have some issue with database,
when i add username, password and click login button It shows '
The requested resource not available' with some session id. Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: You are not telling us which steps of the many suggested here you have taken. Have you changed the filter ? Have you changed the web-app declaration ? Have you checked and eventually aligned all the JARs ?

Comment: Yes, i did all thing u said. but the problem is same. any idea?

Comment: Do you have `<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tags.tld"%>` in your JSP (as first row) ?

Comment: It is right. But then in your jsp, change **all** the `<html:` to `<s:`, like `<html:form action="/login" focus="userName">` to `    <s:form action="/login" focus="userName">`

Comment: now error shows this, 'The requested resource (/LoginExampleStruts1/loginaction) is not available.' when im going to loging with username and password

Comment: lol... there is another mistake: change `action="/login"` to `action="loginaction"`... why are you calling an action with a different namespace ("/" instead of "") and action name from the ones defined in struts.xml ? Change this, it will work.